# CXF Rest Client - set ResponseReader for POJO (JAXBElement)

Tags: java, rest, serialization, jaxb, cxf

I want to transfer a POJO Object with my CXF Rest Client. It already works for JAXB annotated objects. So I had a lot attempts for it.

I tried

```
 reader.setEntityClass(ObjectPOJO.class);
```

and something like

```
 reader.setEntityClass(JAXBElement<ObjectPOJO>.class);
```

Both doesnt work. For the second attempt the code is wrong. I dindt get it to set the entity class to jaxbelement. Maybe it works with it.

After sending the object with:

```
 Response response = client.path(PATH).post(new JAXBElement<ObjectPOJO>(new QName("pojo"), ObjectPOJO.class, pojoObject));
```

i tried to get my entity with different attempts. Something like:

```
 ObjectPOJO pojo = ((JAXBElement<TenantPOJO>) res.getEntity()).getValue();
```

1. Does someone know if I have to register the ObjectPOJO.class or the JAXBElement.class. If second attempt is right, how does it look right in code?
2. Whats the right code to get the entity out of the response?

My Service looks like this:

```
    @POST
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public Response postPojo(JAXBElement<ObjectPOJO> pojo);
```

Edit:

Error

```
 ERROR org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.AbstractClient - .Problem with reading the response message, class : class javax.ws.rs.core.Response, ContentType : application/xml.
```

Answer (score 0):

To transfer objects (PoJos) between rest clients and rest services, there is no need to transfer it using the explicit JAXB conversion. The Jersey container is responsible for the necessary conversion provided the transfer objects are JAXB Annotated Objects.

```
Response response = client.path(PATH).post(postObject);
@XmlRootElement
public class PostObject
{
////
}
```

Comment: I dont use Jersey, it is Apache CXF. I want to transfer a Pojo, not a Jaxb annotated object.